# Why does google keep not show up in the Google Chrome Apps shortcut below the navbar?

Tags: google, google-chrome, google-keep

I was wondering: Why does google keep not show up in the Google Chrome Apps shortcut?
Is it possible to adjust which apps getting displayed there?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Google Keep to your Google Chrome Apps `chrome://apps/`

1. In Chrome, navigate to [keep.google.com](https://keep.google.com/)
2. Click on the [image: 3 dot menu] 3 dot menu
3. Select **More tools > Create shortcut...**
4. Enter a name and click **Create**

Further Reading: [Add & open Chrome apps](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en)